# Running 2 instances of Adobe Analytics in parallel with DTM

Tags: adobe-analytics

I'm trying to migrate my Analytics implementation to DTM by building a second instance and have the old and the new one run in parallel for a while before disabling the old one.

When I browse the site in with DTM staging mode enabled to test the setup, I get collision issues between the two instances. The alternate tracking code variable I specified for the new version is not being defined. Instead of getting a server call for each instances, i get 2x calls from the old one, with a mix of variables values from both designs.

All the setup so far is done throught the DTM interface, no custom code

Adobe Analytics tool library config:

```
Code configuration = custom
Code Hosted = In DTM
Tracker Variable Name = s2   (old one uses "s")
```

The old instance is configured through AEM5.6.1 with H.25
the new one use whatever DTM includes by default

What would be the way to dissociate the 2 instances?

Comment: The basic problem is that on the surface, it's easy enough to change the namespace of the object from `s` to `foo`, but underneath, there are a lot of functions and variables in the global `window` namespace that in no way accounts for or binds to that namespace, so there's all kinds of wtfery with overwriting/bleeding over of variables, depending on how the two load/pop on a given page/interaction.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless someone else has rewritten the core code and hasn't shared, I think you're out of luck for now.  I've been dealing with this same issue for several years now with several clients.  I have repeatedly contacted Adobe about their namespacing and scope creep/bleed-over issues and I've almost no luck getting them to even acknowledge the problem, let alone do something about it.

Comment: Yes, i got passed the first hurdle, to actually assign the object to s2 (i was assuming DTM was creating an instance in the back end instead of me having to explicitely call it). But now i do hit the issues you mention, with various setting overwriting the old versions.  Guess I need to take a few step back a rethink the migration strategy. thanks